# AngularJS $http.post() sends null to ASP.NET web API controller method

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to submit a form from angularjs controller as $http.post() to asp.net web api method. But it sends null value. Here is my code

```
//angular controller
$scope.newpost = {};   
$scope.save = function () {
    console.log($scope.newpost); // it logs data accurately
    $http.post('/api/NewPost', $scope.newpost).
      success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          alert("ok");
      });
}


//api
public HttpResponseMessage post(NewPost newpost) //fields are null here. I tried [FromBody] $ [FromURI], but no luck
{
     posts.Add(newpost);
     String id = newpost.Id; //saving is ok.
     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}


//model
public class NewPost
{
     public String Title { get; set; }
     public String Content { get; set; }
     public String Tags { get; set; }
}

console.log($scope.newpost) displays-
Object {Title: "t", Content: "tt", Tags: "ttt"}
```

Any help?

Comment: Show the `console.log($scope.newpost);` the name of property must match, also before POST do `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
console.log($scope.newpost.Title ); // it should logs data accurately
console.log($scope.newpost.Content );// it should logs data accurately
console.log($scope.newpost.Tags  );// it should logs data accurately
$http.post('/api/NewPost', $scope.newpost).
  success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      alert("ok");
  });
```

Comment: please post $scope.newpost data.

Comment: I found the problem. It comes from MongoRepository. NewPost model was inherited from MongoRepository.Entity. I removed it and the problems is solved.